# Unable to encrypt correctly using CryptoJS in Angular

Tags: angular, encryption, cryptojs

I have following AES encryption to perform in my Angular project where I am using CroyptoJS for this
[Example_aes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYUuw.png)

My code for above encryption is as follows -

```
let keyTool = {
  "vector": "njdsslndlsnlkds",
  "keySource": "abchjkolg@#!djfhrye"
}
let iv = keyTool.vector;

let key = CryptoJS.SHA256(keyTool.keySource).toString().substring(0, 31);

let newkey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
let value = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("abc@gmail.com");
let newIv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv)

let newencrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, newkey, 
  {  
    iv: newIv, 
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });


console.log(newencrypted)
console.log(newencrypted.toString())
```

The encrypted string of my code is - 51d3A1w5NWHy4uagWeRm+C9GYcesDVMSqcsEi9T2c1Y=
Expected is - RBmAWXyJm8d9zV4XaR9BJcLQxTVTM3XEHSHFhGcV75E=

---

Updated:

```
textToEncrypt - "abc@gmail.com"
iv - "njdsslndlsnlkds"
key - "6779b2624c837845a4ec16e7cd1fa40"
other details - CBC, PKCS7, 256 bits (key-length)
cipherText - 51d3A1w5NWHy4uagWeRm+C9GYcesDVMSqcsEi9T2c1Y= (my o/p) 
             Yv9wOiDtSdBS+nWwSqsitg== (website o/p)
```

Comment: @Topaco I have updated the data in the question, pls validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` has UTF-8 encoded only a length of 31 bytes

```
e35417cb037f9911089ec4b94d2360b
```

The website *implicitly*  pads to the 32 bytes length required for AES-256 by appending `0x00` to the end.

In the JavaScript code, the `0x00` value must be *explicitly* appended:

```js
key = key + "\0";
```

Test:

```js
let riskLogicKeyTool = {
    "vector": "njdsslndlsnlkds",
    "keySource": "abchjkolg@#!djfhrye"
}
let iv = riskLogicKeyTool.vector;

let key = CryptoJS.SHA256(riskLogicKeyTool.keySource).toString().substring(0, 31);
key = key + "\0"; // Fix!

let newkey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
let value = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("abc@gmail.com");
let newIv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv)

let newencrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, newkey, 
    {  
        iv: newIv, 
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,      // default 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7   // default    
    });


//console.log(newencrypted);
console.log(newencrypted.toString()); // RBmAWXyJm8d9zV4XaR9BJcLQxTVTM3XEHSHFhGcV75E=
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

---

Both the website and CryptoJS make it harder to identify the problem because they both accept *invalid* keys. Valid key lengths for AES are 16, 24 and 32 bytes. For invalid key lengths, as here with 31 bytes, an appropriate error message/exception should be generated.
In the case of CryptoJS this is a (known) bug, see [issue #293](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293). Care should be taken with crypto websites in general, most are not reliable.

---

It is strange (but may of course meet your requirements) that from the hex encoded SHA-256 hash only 31 instead of 32 bytes are used. Therefore just for completeness: Considering 32 bytes `key` has the value:

```
e35417cb037f9911089ec4b94d2360bf
```

and website and JavaScript code return as ciphertext:

```
YcJO+j3ID9eLbGkFR+TkVDsaO57y28IcHCLzuHOH4zA=
```

---

Security: It is a vulnerability if a fast hash like SHA256 is used as key derivation function. Instead, a reliable key derivation function like PBKDF2 or the more modern scrypt or Argon2 should be used (in combination with a random salt).
Similarly, the use of a static IV is a vulnerability.
In addition, deriving the key from a hex encoded string via UTF-8 encoding reduces security because the range of values per byte is reduced from 256 to 16 values. Also, there may be cross-platform compatibility issues (uppercase, lowercase hex digits).

Answer (score 0):

The encrypted string you're getting is not what you're expecting, and this is because the encryption process is deterministic, meaning that for the same inputs, the output will always be the same.

In your case, it appears that you are using a hardcoded vector and keySource, which means that every time the encryption is performed, the same encrypted string will be produced.

To get a different encrypted string every time, you can either change the input string being encrypted or you can use a unique, randomly generated vector for each encryption.

You can generate a random vector in CryptoJS as follows:

```
let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16).toString();
```

This will generate a random 16-byte word array that you can use as the initial vector (IV) for the encryption.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry you didn't understand my question...I want to generate same encrypted string which I am getting in the online website (image attached)...my code produce some different encrypted string even when same key and vector is used ...question is why output is different ..is my code wrong?